# close call on a SCTP socket is blocking or non blocking?

Tags: sockets, sctp

I am facing an issue, not sure if i can call it an issue or its just understanding gap.

I am calling close() on a `SCTP` socket FD (something like this: close(`sctp_sock_fd);`). I am expecting this close call will return when SCTP SHUTDOWN flow will complete i.e. it will do below then return:

```
SHUTDWON (Source -> Peer)
SHUTDWON_ACK (Source <- Peer)
SHUTDOWN_COMPLETE (Source -> Peer)
```

But what i saw that it looks like `close(sctp_sock_fd);` returned soon after the call, and SCTP shutdown sequence is in progress.

If it is true that its a non-blocking call then is there any way i can ensure that graceful shutdown at `SCTP` Kernel level has completed ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes by default `close()` will be non-blocking on an SCTP socket, it will just initiate the shutdown procedure, not wait for it to complete.

You can change this by setting the SO_LINGER socket option:

```
struct linger lin;
unsigned int len =sizeof(lin);
lin.l_onoff=1;
lin.l_linger=10;
setsockopt(socketfd,SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER,&lin, len);
```

Whith this setting, `close()` will block up to 10 seconds From the [SCTP Socket API RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6458#section-8.1.4):

> 8.1.4.  SO_LINGER
>
> An application can use this option to perform the SCTP ABORT
> primitive.  This option affects all associations related to the
> socket.
>
> The linger option structure is
>
> struct linger {
> int l_onoff;  /* option on/off */
> int l_linger; /* linger time   */    };
>
> To enable the option, set l_onoff to 1.  If the l_linger value is
> set    to 0, calling close() is the same as the ABORT primitive.  If
> the    value is set to a negative value, the setsockopt() call will
> return    an error.  If the value is set to a positive value
> linger_time, the    close() can be blocked for at most linger_time.
> Please note that the    time unit is in seconds, according to POSIX,
> but might be different    on specific platforms.  If the graceful
> shutdown phase does not    finish during this period, close() will
> return, but the graceful    shutdown phase will continue in the
> system.
>
> Note that this is a socket-level option, not an SCTP-level option.
> When using this option, an application must specify a level of
> SOL_SOCKET in the call.

If you're using Linux, there's also [these notes](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/sctp/socket.c#L1426) in the source code.